# Image does not displayed - How to display an image perhaps dynamically

Tags: laravel

I would like to display an employee picture using the url as shown below which I think should work but not. However it does work with the second url which is static. why is this happening?

This the first url that does not work

```
  <img id="message" src="{{url('/profile_picture/' . $employee->picture)}}"   style="width: 150px;"/>
```

This is the second url that does work

```
  <img id="message" src="{{url('/profile_picture/20220615232745.jpg')}}"   style="width: 150px;"/>
```

To save a picture I use the following method

```
public function ProfileStore(Request $request)
{
    $data = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $data->name =$request->name;
    $data->email =$request->email;   
   
     if ($request->file('picture')) {
        $file = $request->file('picture');
        $filename = date('YmdHis') . "." .  $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
         $file->move('profile_picture/',  $filename);
         $data['picture'] = " $filename";
     }
 
     $data->save();

   
    return redirect()->route('profile.index');
}
```

The route

```
Route::post('/people/employees/profiles/store', [ProfileController::class, 'ProfileStore'])->name('profile.store');

Route::get('/people/employees/profiles/edit/{id}', [ProfileController::class, 'ProfileEdit'])->name('profile.edit');
```

My edit method

```
 public function ProfileEdit()
{
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $employee = User::find($id);
 
    return view('fms.people.employee.profiles.profile_edit')->with('employee',$employee);
}
```

Comment: what's in it $employee->picture?
i think because when you save picture, the picture name is already profile_picture, so in view you don't need url('/profile_picture')

src="{{url($employee->picture)}}"

Comment: profile_picture is a directory under app/public. {{dd($employee->picture)}} cointained in a file name 20220615232745.jpg.   $table->string('picture')->nullable();

Comment: may be i suggest you to use laravel storage:link 
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#main-content

Comment: ok I'll give a try

Comment: You have a typo: `$data['picture'] = " $filename";` - there is a space inside the quotes, before `$filename`.  Why are you using quotes at all there?  Why not simply `$data->picture = $filename;`?  Also, for general debugging, you showed us the code which "*does not work*", but what happened? 404s?  If so, did you inspect the generated HTML to find out *why* you got a 404?  What was wrong with the URL, if you compare it to where the image really is on the server?  Was it just the space in the `picture` value or is there also a path problem?

Comment: I have learnt something new from you and it works. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you profilestore function, when setting the $filename to $data['picture'], you have extra space before it.Remove that space and try again. For ex:

```
if ($request->file('picture')) {
    $file = $request->file('picture');
    $filename = date('YmdHis') . "." .  $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
     $file->move('profile_picture/',  $filename);
     $data['picture'] = "$filename";
 }
```